# How to do optimization

Tags: optimization

My teacher gave me a very complicated explanation on how to solve an optimization problem so I just wanted clarification. To do so I have laid out what I think is the simplest way to solve it.

1. Take the derivative of the function given.
2. take $f'(0)$ of the derivative to get the critical number.
3. Plug in both the critical number to original function and also plug in the extreme values (i.e. if it gives you a control of $[-5,5]$ or $0<x<200$).

And from those answers you can see your max and min?

Comment: Step 2, Did you mean "take the derivative $f'(x)$ and solve $f'(x)=0$ in order to find the critical numbers if any"?

Answer (score 0):

See some ideas below, keep in mind that there are many techniques to solve optimization problems.

Case 1: Unconstrained optimization problem:

1. Derivative of the function $f'(x)$
2. Compute $f''(x)$ to check is your objective function is semidefinite or definite.
3. If your problem is convex then solve $f'(x)=0$ and substitute in the objective function, since your stationary point will be the optimal solution.

Case 2: Constrained optimization problem:

The common procedures are establish the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions or compute the lagrangian to solve your problem as an unconstrained problem.